# Can't Install Python Packages with pip

Tags: python, terminal

I am using a windows system pc and I am having alot of trouble installing python libraries like numpy, scipy, and matplotlib. Everytime I try to do a pip installation like 'pip install numpy', it submits an error report. Pip and Python is already updated to the latest version, and I have python added to PATH.

I've looked everywhere around the internet to find the solution but nothing worked. I have tried to reinstall python, download cmake, and install a previous version. It'something about building wheels for ninja and backend dependencies, but I am not sure how I would go about fixing this issue. How do I fix this error message so I can continue using python?

Here below is the output for installing numpy, similar to other python libraries.

```
D:\python311>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Using cached ninja-1.11.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [9 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mrhvwz_r\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mrhvwz_r\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mrhvwz_r\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have also did 'pip install --verbose numpy' to see a more detailed explanation.

```
D:\python311>pip install --verbose numpy
Using pip 23.2.1 from C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.26.0.tar.gz (15.6 MB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Ignoring setuptools: markers 'python_version >= "3.12"' don't match your environment
  Collecting Cython<3.1,>=0.29.34
    Obtaining dependency information for Cython<3.1,>=0.29.34 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/e9/9cc0c4f0d8a566089d096254cd25168a0db02dd047863a7f995d8d3eefa7/Cython-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
    Using cached Cython-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
  Collecting pyproject-metadata>=0.7.1
    Using cached pyproject_metadata-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
  Collecting tomli>=1.0.0
    Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
  Collecting colorama
    Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
  Collecting packaging>=19.0 (from pyproject-metadata>=0.7.1)
    Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
  Using cached Cython-3.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Installing collected packages: tomli, packaging, Cython, colorama, pyproject-metadata
  Successfully installed Cython-3.0.2 colorama-0.4.6 packaging-23.1 pyproject-metadata-0.7.1 tomli-2.0.1
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command pip subprocess to install backend dependencies
  Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
    Using cached ninja-1.11.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
    Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
    Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [9 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a04oa8_d\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
        cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
      File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a04oa8_d\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
        self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
      File "C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-a04oa8_d\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
        raise SKBuildError(msg) from err

    Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
  Failed to build ninja
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe' 'C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\__pip-runner__.py' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\nishi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ikxu5dzv\normal' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'ninja >= 1.8.2'
  cwd: [inherit]
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

It seems that 'Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error''

Comment: `numpy` uses `C/C++` code and it may needs to install `C/C++ compiler` and other tools for `C/C++` (like `CMake` which you can see in error message). If you run `pip` with `--verbose` then it may show more details. `pip install --verbose numpy`

Comment: you can install these library with [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/)
Conda manage all dep you need to install these library

Comment: `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10` looks strange. Looks like you may have multiple versions of Python in your PATH, one installed by MSYS. Also, just to make sure: 64-bit Python? (`python --version`).

Comment: @AKX should I delete my python 3.10.6 PATH in my environmental variables? I do have two version for python since some softwares are not yet supported with the latest one, and I am running the pip command on my 3.11.5 path.  Even If I uninstall python 3.11.5, it gives me the same error with 3.10.6.

Comment: Well, you could try using the `py` launcher to always choose the right version...